# How to use shape position with label

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, shapes

If I show a circle with specific x and y coordinates it works fine:

```
public class FxApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();

        Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 2);
        group.getChildren().add(circle);

        Pane pane = new Pane(group);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(pane);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: only circle]

But if I add a label to the circle the position of the circle is ignored.

```
public class FxApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();

        Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 2);
        Label label = new Label("test", circle);
        group.getChildren().add(label);

        Pane pane = new Pane(group);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(pane);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: with label]

**How to keep the position of the circle and only add the label or how to set the correct circle position inclusive label?**

For example what works is:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(circle_center_x, circle_center_y, 3);
Text label = new Text("test");
double halfLabelHeight = label.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2;
label.relocate(circle_center_x + 10, circle_center_y - halfLabelHeight);
this.getChildren().addAll(circle , label);
```

But I'm looking for a more integrated solution. I thought the Label object could be somewhat smart and do this on it's own but instead it's taking the circle x and y position and applies that to it's own space and not the parent space.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to relocate the label now instead of just telling the circle where to be displayed. When you specify the `new Circle(100,100,2)` you telling the Circle Object to be located at the x=100 and y=100 of its parent. In the first case its parent is the `group` but in the second case, its parent is now the `Label`. In order to locate the Label to x,y = 100,100 inside the Group you will need to call :

```
label.relocate(100, 100);
```

The Circle initialization is now not necessary. Even if you put the Circle at 0,0 it's still going to be displayed next to the Label because the label will manage the Node location.

PS. You can either change the NodeOrientation from LEFT_TO_RIGHT to RIGHT_TO_LEFT by `label.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);` or in case you want to change the "shape" location you can do `label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);` ( or BOTTOM etc )

I am not sure I understand correct what are you trying to achieve here but I guess you want to have the Circle and the Label next to each other. In addition you want to label to be centered on height depending the circle location. If the previous assumption is correct then here is the code to achieve that  :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxApplication extends Application {

    private Group group;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        group = new Group();

        addCustomNode(100, 100, new Circle(2), new Label("Test"));

        Pane pane = new Pane(group);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(pane);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void addCustomNode(int x, int y, Circle circle, Label label) {

        double labelDimensions[] = getLabelDimensions(label);

        circle.setCenterX(100);
        circle.setCenterY(100);

        label.relocate(circle.getCenterX() + labelDimensions[0] / 2.0, circle.getCenterY() - labelDimensions[1] / 2.0);

        group.getChildren().addAll(circle, label);

    }

    // find the height and width before we
    // add the label to the stage
    private double[] getLabelDimensions(Label label) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label("Hello");
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene s = new Scene(h);
        l.impl_processCSS(true);

        return new double[] { l.prefWidth(-1), l.prefHeight(-1) };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't put the circle on the right position. My x and y coordinates should be the center of the circle. This should still hold with the label. With relocate this doesn't hold.

Comment: @Spen Maybe I haven't understand you correctly. If you don't really want to wrap the shape with the Label why don't you just add them both to the Group? `group.getChildren().addAll(label,circle);` ( of course you must not add the circle to the Label too). Am I missing something? Could you show us what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the circle to be at a specific position (the circle center should be on x / y). To this circle I want to add a label that should be on the right side of the circle and centered. The circle position shouldn't change at all. If I add the label additionally to the circle the label is not centered besides the circle. I did hope that I don't need to calculate the center and then correct the position and instead to just use a existing javafx component that just adds a label to what ever object I give it with the label being centered on the right side of the object.

Comment: @Spen In order for Label to be 'centered' I am guessing you want both of them to be inside a pane ( FlowPane, HBox etc) and then the Label has to be on the right side of the Circle and centered to the whole pane (width , height) + the Circle has to be at 100,100 of the `Group` and not on its actual Pane right?

Comment: @Spen This just sounds like an [X-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To achieve a specific layout, you should use an appropriate layout pane. You can control the position of text relative to the graphic in a label with the `contentDisplay` property. But it's really unclear what you're trying to do. I don't even understand which coordinate system you think you're referring to when you say you want the center of the circle at `(100, 100)`. The label's coordinate system? Someone else's?

Comment: You are both right. I probably don't express my problem very well at all. But I don't know how to. I'm just adding multiple shapes to one pane and every shape has it's own coordinates it gets positioned on the pane. Now there are these dots and I just want to put a label beside them (so the dots are already on the pane on the right position. I just thought the labe would get added on the right side of the circle (vertically centered to the circle) and the circle position wouldn't change. I don't care about any sub group the circle is just positioned on this one pane and the label should be too

Comment: I added a example solution that solves my problem as I'm thinking of it. But that is explicitly not the solution I was looking for. I didn't wanted to do any pixel calculation and did hope that JavaFx would provide any component that already solves this problem.